# C# route example

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I have a problem with my program. I have no other idea to make it.

Here is my attempt:

```
public static string routegen(string filename)
    {
        string[] directions = readwrite.linesread(filename);

        int beginx = int.Parse(directions[0].Substring(0,1));
        int beginy = int.Parse(directions[0].Substring(2));

        string inwhich = "dodecagon";
        int dbsquare = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < directions.Length; ++i)
        {
            if (inwhich == "dodecagon")
            {
                if (directions[i] == "N") ++beginy;
                if (directions[i] == "S") --beginy;
                if (directions[i] == "E") ++beginx;
                if (directions[i] == "W") --beginx;

                if (directions[i] == "WSW" || directions[i] == "ESE") inwhich = "triangletop";
                if (directions[i] == "WNW" || directions[i] == "ENE") inwhich = "trianglebottom";
                if (directions[i] == "NNE" || directions[i] == "SSE") inwhich = "triangleleft";
                if (directions[i] == "NNW" || directions[i] == "SSW") inwhich = "triangleright";


            }

            if (inwhich == "square")
            {
                ++dbsquare;

                if (directions[i] == "N")
                {
                    inwhich = "triangletop";
                    ++beginy;
                }
                if (directions[i] == "S")
                {
                    inwhich = "trianglebottom";
                    --beginy;
                }
                if (directions[i] == "W")
                {
                    inwhich = "triangleleft";
                    --beginx;
                }
                if (directions[i] == "E")
                {
                    inwhich = "triangleright";
                    ++beginx;
                }
            }

            if (inwhich == "triangletop")
            {
                if (directions[i] == "WNW")
                {
                    --beginx;
                    inwhich = "dodecagon";
                }

                if (directions[i] == "ENE")
                {
                    ++beginx;
                    inwhich = "dodecagon";
                }

                if (directions[i] == "S")
                {
                    //--beginy;
                    inwhich = "square";
                }

            }

            if (inwhich == "trianglebottom")
            {
                if (directions[i] == "WSW")
                {
                    --beginx;
                    inwhich = "dodecagon";
                }

                if (directions[i] == "ESE")
                {
                    ++beginx;
                    inwhich = "dodecagon";
                }

                if (directions[i] == "N")
                {
                    //++beginy;
                    inwhich = "square";
                }
            }

            if (inwhich == "triangleleft")
            {
                if (directions[i] == "NNW")
                {
                    ++beginy;
                    inwhich = "dodecagon";
                }

                if (directions[i] == "SSW")
                {
                    --beginy;
                    inwhich = "dodecagon";
                }

                if (directions[i] == "E")
                {
                    //++beginx;
                    inwhich = "square";
                }
            }

            if (inwhich == "triangleright")
            {
                if (directions[i] == "NNE")
                {
                    ++beginy;
                    inwhich = "dodecagon";
                }

                if (directions[i] == "SSE")
                {
                    --beginy;
                    inwhich = "dodecagon";
                }

                if (directions[i] == "W")
                {
                    //--beginx;
                    inwhich = "square";
                }
            }
```

There are dodecagons and between them there are triangles and squares. The program gets the start coordinates from a text file first line ( ex. 1 1 ) and from the other lines it gets the directions ( there are 12 direction: N NNE ENE E ESE SSE S SSW WSW W WNW NNW N).

The task is to give back the final dodecagon coordinates, the number of the squares in the route and the number of the dodecagons which occured more than once.

I attached a picture with an example.

The directions: 1 1 ENE N N ENE E WSW D E SSE

Here is the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnxIc.png

The solution: final coordinates: 3 1 squares: 2 decagons occured more than once: 0

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: I have tried with if statements, but with it some route doesn't work because the final dodecagon coordinates are wrong.

Comment: This looks like schoolwork. The main point of the exercise is to get you to understand the problem and the algorithms involved, then write the program. It's not to get the Internet to write the program for you. Besides, most teachers will require an explanation of the program and how/why it works. In any case, SO is a Q&A site. Please post a concrete question with the code you tried and the problems you encountered. Please check [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Think about what you are doing when you trace the route by hand. Then try to explain it to a "rubber duck" that can't *see* the map. This should get you started. And when you have *specific* questions, post another one.

Comment: here is : https://gist.github.com/865afe33a06eecfcce5e.git

Comment: I haven't wanted to write it for me. I have no idea how to do it. I would like to get an idea not a complete solution.

Comment: Most of us are not going to click on your links or even go as far as pull that git repo... so, post your relevant code and images here.  It's not very hard.